# Run tsc command from root

Tags: typescript

I have this folder structure:

```
project
   |
    ---amplify
          |
           ---backend
                 |
                  ---tsconfig.json
```

When i am inside the `backend` folder i can just run `tsc` and it will compile all my ts files inside this folder. How do i run this command from the `project` folder.

I tried with:

`tsc ./amplify/backend`

Does not work

Also tried:

`tsc ./amplify/backend/tsconfig.json`

Also doesnt work

Comment: `tsc --project path/to/file`? Do you have any package files? Scripts? Are these workspaces?

Comment: @jonrsharpe a bit of context. I will write this command inside my `amplify.yml` file so this command will run in the pre-build phase when i push it into the cloud.

Comment: I think you could also do a `cd ./amplify/backend && tsc`